# Problems with updating composite keys in sonata admin bundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I am new to sonata admin bundle

I have created a form in sonata admin bundle.

```
 protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
   {

    $formMapper
    ->with('General')

    ->add('userid', null, array('label' => 'User'))
    ->add('cityid', null, array('label' => 'City Name'))

    ->end();    
   }
```

Here `userid` and `cityid` are composite key.

I am able to create a new record successfully. But Updation  on the same record by changing any one of the composite key creates a problem.

The record is updated successfully in the database but it throws the exception

```
unable to find the object with id : 1~1
```

where 1~1 is the id of user and city prior its updation. How do i resolve this Exception?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you are trying to manually create/update records for M:N relation.
This isn't needed, because Dotrine ORM will create or delete these records in middle table for M:N relation automatically.

- Check, that you have correct relations in your database structure. You can visualize your database structure in some database modeling application, like [Mysql Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).
- Map correctly your database structure to doctrine config files.
  Reverse engineering of your database may help:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html
  In doctrine config file "User.orm.xml" should be *many-to-many* relation. For example:

```
    <many-to-many field="cityId" target-entity="City" inversed-by="userId">
      <join-table name="user_has_city">
        <join-columns>
          <join-column name="id_user" referenced-column-name="id_user"/>
        </join-columns>
        <inverse-join-columns>
          <join-column name="city_id" referenced-column-name="city_id"/>
        </inverse-join-columns>
      </join-table>
    </many-to-many>
```

- Add __toString() method to your City entity:

  ```
  //...some code of entity...

  public function __toString()
  {
      return $this->name; //or $this->title, $this->label etc. - based on the name of variable, which stores the city's name.
  }
  ```
- In file AcmeExampleBundle/Admin/UserAdmin.php:

  ```
  $formMapper
          ->add('cityId', 'sonata_type_model', array(
              'required' => false,
              'label'    => $this->trans('City name'),
              'expanded' => true,
              ));
  ```